# Delete temporary folder's contents

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, delete-file, directory

My program uses this code to delete its temp folder:

```
    // ...
    if (!RemoveDirectory(L"C:\\MyTemp"))
        return false;

    if (!CreateDirectory(L"C:\\MyTemp", NULL))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
    // ...
```

But, actually I must delete temp's contents (subfolders and files in it) and at the moment of deleting some files may be in use by the program. How can this code be written in a more better form? I'd appreciate your little code sample.

Comment: If your program uses files and you try to delete them I think you have serious problems in your architecture.

Comment: Just as a side note: it's not always good to assume everyone's partitions are mapped out to where their root drive is C:. For example, my XP partition is D: and my Win 7 Partition is E:, my C: drive is extra space. So running this program for me would not do as instructed.

Comment: @alestanis: unless the code was originally written for Posix, in which case deleting files while using them works and is sometimes entirely reasonable. On Posix "deleting" a file just unlinks one name for the file, so other names and programs with open file handlers need not be affected at all.

Comment: @alestanis: the program has multiple temp files, and it must delete files which are not being used. M4rc: program itself for learning purposes, and at the moment I have "C:\\MyTemp" in my PC! Thanks for understanding. Guys, I just want to delete these files!

Answer (score 0):

A non-portable solution is `SHFileOperation()` from `<Shellapi.h>`. The structure used contains a `fAnyOperationsAborted` member, which will tell you if any of the files could not be deleted.